# systemd trying to start MariaDB twice (mariadb@multi-user.service vs mariadb.service)

Tags: fedora, systemd, mariadb

systemd on my system seems to be trying to start MariaDB twice.  This first try succeeds, so my system has no real problems, but the second try creates spurious error messages since all the relevant files have been locked by the first instance.

As far as I can tell, it's starting once for `mariadb@multi-user.service` and once for `mariadb.service`.  The result of `systemctl list-units | grep -i maria` is:

```
● mariadb.service
                        loaded failed     failed    MariaDB 10.2 database server
  mariadb@multi-user.service
                        loaded active     running   MariaDB 10.2 database server
  system-mariadb.slice
                        loaded active     active    system-mariadb.slice
```

I'm *guessing* that things will be fine if I tell systemd to disable `mariadb.service`, but I'd prefer not to guess.

My system is Fedora 28.  The installed MairaDB packages are:

```
mariadb-config-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-rocksdb-engine-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-backup-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-cracklib-password-check-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-connector-c-3.0.5-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-server-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-common-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-server-utils-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-tokudb-engine-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-gssapi-server-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
mariadb-errmsg-10.2.16-1.fc28.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instantiatable unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@.service` explains what is going on:

> ```
> # Multi instance version of mariadb. For if you run mutiple verions at once.
> # Also used for mariadb@bootstrap to bootstrap Galera.
> #
> # To use multi instance variant, use [mysqld.INSTANCENAME] as sections in my.cnf
> # and start the service via:
> #       systemctl start mariadb@{instancename}.server
> ```

So, someone in the past did exactly that, creating an instanced MariaDB with the name `multi-user`. That name suggests to me that it was probably a mistake, rather than intentional.

How you solve the problem depends on whether you want to keep the instantiated service or not. Disable one or the other service, edit the my.cnf appropriately, and restart the other service. Most people don't need to instantiate MariaDB running multiple copies at once, and you're probably most people.